# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am using java 1.8 and spring boot 2.7.14 and tomcat 8.5. i package as war. i deploy it in tomcat webapps. but I am getting below error. please help me with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.14</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test2</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application run failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4925) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:710) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.91]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
        ... 31 common frames omitted

24-Jul-2023 18:29:10.425 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:710)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:687)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4925)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 10 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
                ... 30 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
                ... 31 more
24-Jul-2023 18:29:10.427 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Users\kumarper\Documents\apache-tomcat-8.5.91-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.91\webapps\test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:714)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:687)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1016)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:710)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1232)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4925)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 10 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
                ... 30 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
                ... 31 more
```

Comment: You need to add default main entry class constructor. ( MainApplication.java )

Comment: <start-class>com.baeldung.DemoApplication</start-class> I added it but it did not work.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7 doesn't support JakartaEE and you included JakartaEE api version of the servlet api.

Comment: I added it. <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> but it did not work.

Comment: In my case I was passing SpringApplication.class as a param to run method instead of my main class name SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args)). I fixed this by passing MainApplication.class to the run method SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args))